# Missing link flags for targets when using set_target_properties and LINK_FLAGS

Tags: cmake, solaris, linker-flags

We have three targets. One is a static library, one is a shared library and one is a program. We are trying to add target specific linker flags to the shared library and program.

When we try to append the flags we need:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "SunPro")
    CRYPTOPP_XARCH_OPTIONS = "-xarch=ssse3 -xarch=sse4_1 ..."
endif()
...

if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "SunPro")
    set_target_properties(cryptest-program PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS APPEND "-M cryptest.mapfile")
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cryptest.mapfile DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
    set_target_properties(cryptest-program PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS APPEND ${CRYPTOPP_XARCH_OPTIONS})
endif ()
```

It results in a failure:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:631 (set_target_properties):
 set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
```

When we attempt to use `X = ${X} Y` syntax due to a missing `+= operator`, then the properties are silently dropped:

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "SunPro")
    set_target_properties(cryptest-program PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${LINK_FLAGS} "-M cryptest.mapfile")
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cryptest.mapfile DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
    set_target_properties(cryptest-program PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS ${LINK_FLAGS} ${CRYPTOPP_XARCH_OPTIONS})
endif ()
```

For example, the mapfile was lost so testing under Solaris on early Xeon's results in:

```
$ ./cryptest.exe v
ld.so.1: cryptest.exe: fatal: cryptest.exe: hardware capability (CA_SUNW_HW_1) unsupported: 0x4800000  [ AES SSE4.1 ]
Killed
```

Here are the docs for [`set_property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set_property.html),[`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/set_target_properties.html) and [`LINK_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/LINK_FLAGS.html). They don't provide the necessary details and fail to provide examples. The doc for `set_target_properties` is especially charming.

How do we add target specific link flags?

Comment: Documentation pages for CMake commands are **detailed** actually: they contain almost full information for *proper* using of commands. Documentation for `set_property` describes *APPEND* option, and the command actually accepts it. As opposite, documentation for `set_target_properties` doesn't describe this option, and the command doesn't accept it. As you can see from signature, only *single-valued* (not lists) properties can be set with `set_target_properties`. As for "charming", it is probably because of *misprint*: "files" should be read as "properties".

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/target_link_libraries.html) for linker flags.

```
set(CRYPTOPP_XARCH_OPTIONS 
  -xarch=ssse3 
  -xarch=sse4_1 
  ...)
target_link_libraries(cryptest-program
  -M cryptest.mapfile
  ${CRYPTOPP_XARCH_OPTIONS})
```

Note that in all cases you're dealing with lists, not strings like you would have to manage with the `LINK_FLAGS` property. The somewhat unnecessary indentation above is to emphasize that fact.